# NFC Peer-to-peer between two PN532s using Python

Tags: python, nfc, i2c, nfc-p2p, pn532

I am trying to setup a P2P network with two PN532 v3 chips.
They are connected to respective Raspberry Pi 4Bs via I2C.
I just need to be able to detect, send and receive data between them.

Most libraries either don't support I2C or P2P. Some have P2P with an android but that is not what I'm looking for.

Does anyone have any documentation/ libraries that might be useful to achieve this?

Comment: The nfcpy library (https://github.com/nfcpy/nfcpy) supports P2P. But you would need to use UART connection instead of I2C.

Comment: If it runs Linux, can you check if in-kernel driver supports what you need?